# executing shell script with nohup commands via python scripts

Tags: python, shell, nohup

Hi I am new to Python scripting. I am trying to execute jboss startup shell script through python. The shell script when executed directly works fine, but when trying to execute through python it is not working fine. I have here by attached my shell script and also python script as well. Please help me.

First, the shell script being run -- `start_jboss.sh`:

```
#export JAVA_HOME=/opt/appserver/jdk1.7.0_79/
export INSTANCE=jbstd-rss-D04
export JBOSS_HOME=/opt/appserver/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/
export CONF_HOME=/opt/appserver/JBOSS/jbstd-rss-D04/standalone/
export LOGFILEPATH=/opt/logs/jboss/${INSTANCE}


export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xverify:none  -
    Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -
    Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -server -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -
    XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -Xms1024M -
    Xmx1024M -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/opt/logs/jboss/${INSTANCE}/gc.log -
    XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -
    XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=2 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M"

nohup sh ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh -
    Djboss.server.base.dir=${CONF_HOME} -
    Djboss.server.config.dir=$CONF_HOME/configuration/ -c standalone-full-ha.xml 
    -Djboss.node.name=jbstd-rss-D01      
  Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/appserver/JBOSS/SSL/truststores/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=Was6user1 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/appserver/JBOSS/SSL/keystores/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=Was6user1 -Djboss.server.log.dir=${LOGFILEPATH} -DlogFilePath=${LOGFILEPATH} -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=300 -DRSS_HOME=/opt/appserver/rss >> /dev/null &
```

Second, the Python wrapper, `start_jboss_service.py`:

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import os
import subprocess

#get the instance names to start instances
input=str(sys.stdin.read())
instances=input.split(',')
numberOfInstances=len(instances)
jboss_home="/opt/appserver/JBOSS/"

if (numberOfiInstances > 0):
        for i in (0,numberOfInstances):
                cmd="%s%s/start_jboss.sh"%(jboss_home,instances[i])
                subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

...being started as follows:

```
python start_jboss_service.py jbstd-rss-D04
```

Comment: If you set `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, then you need to actually *read* anything written to that file descriptor (before `nohup` detaches from it, of course), or the process will block indefinitely.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `shell=True` here? It introduces room for bugs (for instance, if your input contains `$(touch /tmp/evil)`, that will be run as a command by the shell), and doesn't actually add anything useful.

Comment: Can you let me know how to format the subprocess then ? i do not need the stdout=subprocess.PIPE (included considering it was the syntax)

Comment: Actually, there's another, bigger problem: You're reading from stdin, but you're passing arguments on the command line, not stdin. So the name of the process you want to start isn't even getting to the `input` variable in the first place.

Comment: BTW, the shell script is several kinds of broken -- it needs line continuations but doesn't have them. You can't split `-Dfoo=bar` to a `-` at the end of one line and a `D` at the start of the next one, and if you're going to split a single command onto multiple lines, you need to use explicit continuations (a trailing backslash at the end of each line) except in the limited number of contexts where a newline *isn't* treated as a command separator.

Comment: BTW, if you get an error without `shell=True`, one likely cause of that is your script needing a shebang (such as `#!/bin/bash`) to be executable from a non-shell program without it, *even if the execute permission is set*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue One: Blocking Subprocess Output

You're redirecting output to a pipeline, but then you're never actually *consuming* content from that pipeline. Even though `nohup` will redirect to `/dev/null` after it starts, anything that tries to write prior to that point will be blocked on the buffer being consumed, preventing anything in your script *after* that attempted write from taking place.

You have two options:

- Remove `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, and let your script write directly to the Python process's original stdout.
- Call `communicate()` on the `Popen` object you've constructed.

Taking the former approach, your command may simply become:

```
for instance in string.split(input, ','):
  if not instance: continue  # ignore trailing or doubled-up commas
  subprocess.Popen(['%s%s/start_jboss.sh' % (jboss_home, instance)])
```

---

#### Issue Two: Reading Command-Line Arguments

If you run `python start_jboss_service.py jbstd-rss-D04`, `sys.stdin.read()` **does not** return `jbstd-rss-D04`: This is not passed on standard input, but on the argument list.

Thus, you need to remove the line `sys.stdin.read()`, and instead parse the argument list.

And if you accept multiple arguments, you should pass each instance name as a separate argument -- at which point you don't need to split on commas at all:

```
for instance in sys.argv[1:]:
    subprocess.Popen(['%s%s/start_jboss.sh' % (jboss_home, instance)])
```

Comment: i changed the subprocess  -  subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

After executing python, its still the same. :(

Comment: That's not the only change I'm asking you to make. You have multiple problems, so you need to make multiple corrections.

Comment: I've edited to be a bit more explicit that parsing input *from the command line* means you should stop reading that input from stdin (which, unless you send an EOF or redirect from an input that terminates, will indeed make your program appear to hang).